# Error invalid parameters with REST API

Tags: rest-api

Trying to use the Wordpress API to create a blog post with tags/categories, etc. but running into some errors. I am running the PHP code below outside of my Wordpress instance and get the following:

CODE

```
function CreatePost($title, $content, $tag){
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $category = 'test category words name test';
    $rest_api_url = "https://www.urlurlurlurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

$data_string = json_encode([
    'title'    => $title,
    'content'  => $content,
    'status'   => 'publish',
    'tags' => 'test tag',
    'category' => $category
]);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rest_api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
}
```

ERROR

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): tags","data":{"status":400,"params":{"tags":"tags[0] is not of type integer."}}}
```

Comment: The error "*tags[0] is **not of type integer*** means you need to provide tag IDs and not names, etc.

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ - I tried both 'category' => '5' and 'category' => 5 but neither seemed to work? No error, there is a category_id 5 for sure...

Comment: Also is there a way for me to always use the name instead of the ID? This is how it works with XMLRPC?

Comment: I've just posted an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in question — "*Invalid parameter(s): tags*" and "*tags[0] is **not of type integer**.*", means that you need to supply a list of tag IDs and not names or slugs. So for examples, `'tags' => 123` and `'tags' => [ 123 ]` are both valid. (Comma-separated list is also accepted, e.g. `'tags' => '123,4,5'`.)

And all that also apply to the default `category` taxonomy and custom taxonomies (e.g. `my_tax`), except that for `category`, you should use [`categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post) and not `category`. So for example, use `'categories' => 5` and not `'category' => 5`.

From your comment:

> is there a way for me to always use the name instead of the ID?

You can try one of these (or both for testing..):

1. You can first create the tag/category using the REST API (e.g. [`/wp/v2/categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#create-a-category) for categories) and get the tag/category ID from the API response, and then use it when creating your post.

   So you'd be making two REST API requests, one for creating the tag/category, and another for creating the post.
2. On your WordPress site, you can [register custom REST API fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#adding-custom-fields-to-api-responses) like `tags_name` and `categories_slug`:

   ```php
   // In your theme functions.php file:

   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_rest_fields' );
   function my_register_rest_fields() {
       register_rest_field( 'post', 'tags_name', [
           'update_callback' => function ( $names, $post ) {
               return wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, $names );
           }
       ] );

       register_rest_field( 'post', 'categories_slug', [
           'update_callback' => function ( $slugs, $post ) {
               $ids = [];

               foreach ( wp_parse_list( $slugs ) as $slug ) {
                   if ( $category = get_category_by_slug( $slug ) ) {
                       $ids[] = $category->term_id;
                   }
               }

               return ( ! empty( $ids ) ) ?
                   wp_set_post_categories( $post->ID, $ids ) : false;
           }
       ] );
   }
   ```

   Then when creating your post, in the API request body/data, use `'categories_slug' => 'cat-one, cat-two, etc'` for categories, and `'tags_name' => 'one, two, etc'` for tags. And remember, for *categories*, you need to use the category *slug* and not name.